# is there a way to simplify $x^{2} ( v' (x^{n})' )$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

so I have what is probably an algebra question, if I have $x^{2} ( v' (x^{n})' )$ where the ' denotes a derivative, is there a way to simplify this expression?

Comment: derivatives are with respect to x by the way, and v is a function of x

Comment: I assume you want $$ x^2 \cdot \frac {\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( x^n \right)? $$ If this is the case, I'll provide an answer.

Comment: actually the x^n is also differentiated!I ask beacuse I know x^2 * x^n is x^n+2 but is there something similar I can do in the above case?

Comment: So you want to simplify $ x^2 \cdot v'(x) \cdot \left( x^{n} \right)' $?

Comment: yes exactly thats what i need

Comment: I have added an answer. You cannot combine $x^2$ and $x^n$ like you said above, since the $x^n$ is differentiated by the $x^2$ is not, and you cannot combine like that. Hope the answer helped!

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$ \begin {align*} x^2 \cdot v'(x) \cdot \left( x^n \right)' &= x^2 \cdot v'(x) \cdot nx^{n-1} \\&= nx^{n+1} \cdot v'(x), \end {align*} $$ which is as far as you can get if you don't know $v(x)$.